# Does aws documentdb validate mongodb client certificate for two way ssl?

Tags: mongodb, openssl, mongodb-java, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

How do we create client certificate to get validated by aws document db?In aws docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled, it is mentioned only about one way ssl i.e.,clients authenticating server certificate.I didn't find information regarding two way ssl supported by aws document db.Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon DocumentDB does not support using client certificates to connect to your cluster. Are you looking for client-side certificates to be used by the server for authentication? Amazon DocumentDB only supports SCRAM based authentication.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Yes,looking to create a client certificate and get it validated by server for two way ssl.